# number formatting issues when reading excel with xlrd

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, xlrd

Is there an UNDOCUMENTED way of reading cell number format in xlrd?

I'm reading `.xlsx` files and the 'formatting_info' was not and will not be implemented.

My data looks like this:

```
     Brand A| Brand B| Brand C|
row1|  45%  |  25%   |  25%   |
row2|  24%  |  8%    |  8%    |
row3|  0.5  |  4     |  0.14  |
```

I need to read the data as it appears in excel.

A few key points to consider:

1. I'm not allowed to change libraries, I have to use xlrd
2. The data types are not fixed, any given row can have percent or int
3. I'm using `xlsx` files therefore `formatting_info=True` is not an option as it's only availble on `xls` not `xlsx`

How would I tackle this issue?

Comment: Just for my own curiosity, why are you not allowed to use a different library?

Comment: We have built our excel parsing infrastructure around xlrd, it would mean we'd have to rewrite/change everything if we change

Comment: Can you cleanly convert the xlsx to xls? If so, you could just convert the file in the script then load the converted file.

Answer (score -2):

As a first guess, I would say that checking that for a whole line, if all value are `0 <= x <= 1` then it probably are percentages.

If you want to be sure, you will have to check the formatting of the cells.

Firstly, add `formatting_info=True` to your `xlrd.open_workbook(filepath)` which allows you to do `cell_format = book.xf_list[cell.xf_index]`.

This is the [XF format](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.formatting.XF) that originates from the Excel data structure, but with it you can check your `book.format_map[cell_format.format_key]` which has two attributes : `type` and `format_str`, whose values are defined [in the documentation](https://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf) (page 174, chapter 5.49 "Format").

Comment: I'm sure that formatting_info is not available on xlsx files, I think it is only available on xls files.